# How to append checkbox value to an li

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys, so I would like you to help with an issue that I'm having, pretty much what i need is when the checkbox is clicked to append the checkbox value to an li element in a different div. Check the html below. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="heading">
    <p><a href="#">Experiences</a></p>
    <a href="#" target="_self">modify</a>                
</div><!--heading-->
<div class="add-filters">
    <div class="inner">
        <h4 class="title-filtery">Filtery By:</h4>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="adventure" name="adventure" /> <label for="adventure">Adventure</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="diving" name="diving" /> <label for="diving">Diving</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="beach" name="beach" /> <label for="beach">Beach</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="ecotour" name="ecotour" /> <label for="ecotour">Eco-Tour</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="boating" name="boating" /> <label for="boating">Boating</label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="family" name="family" /> <label for="family">Family</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="canoe" name="canoe" /> <label for="canoe">Canoe/Kayak/Raft</label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="btn-holder clearfix">
            <input type="button" class="btn-cancel" value="" />
            <input type="button" class="btn-update" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- filters -->
<div class="hidden-filters">
    <p>Filtering by:</p>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div><!-- hidden-filters -->
```

Comment: And so with what part of this are you having a problem?

Comment: I want to create a function that when you click on the checkbox it populates the ul element inside an li element (the ul is under .hidden-filters)

Comment: Attach a function to the checkbox click event and then target div in this function and do what you need...

Comment: oh you want the code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this, <del>but note I've not covered how to remove the inserted `li` elements from the list when/if they're unchecked</del> (See after the `hr`):

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:checkbox').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 $('<li />').appendTo('#div ul').text($(this).val());   
                }
            }); 
    });
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhGtp/).

---

Edited to offer a removal facility, if the `checkbox` is unchecked:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:checkbox').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 $('<li />').appendTo('#div ul').text($(this).val());   
                }
                else {
                    $('#div li:contains('+$(this).val()+')').remove();
                }
            }); 
    });
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhGtp/1/).

Comment: No, *thank you* for the accept; and always glad to be of help =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     var val = $(this).val();
     $('.hidden-filters > ul').append('<li>'+val+'</li>');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    $(".hidden-filters").append("<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>");
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly the only thing that I saw is that if you keep on clicking on the checkbox, it would continue populating the checkbox value. Any advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Ozzy, have a look at my answer, though you'll have to fill in the requisite element names yourself.