# How do I get multiple values from checked checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get multiple values from checked checkboxes and display them in a `<p></p>` tag. I also want to add the functionality to remove a selection by adding a **cross (x)** next to it.

I know there are many similar questions asked already on stackoverflow like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147493/get-checkbox-value-into-a-div-like-content), I haven't found a solution that works for me yet though.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026651/how-to-append-checkbox-value-to-an-li) question on stackoverflow and it works great when checking the checkboxes BUT when you de-select a checkbox that has already been selected, all of the selections are removed as opposed to the one that was unchecked.

```js
$('input:checkbox[name="skills"]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('<span />').appendTo('#filter-2-result').text($(this).val());
  } else {
    $('#filter-2-result:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Skills:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="filter" id="filter-2-result"><span class="deselect"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSkills">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#skillsCollapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="skillsCollapse">
          Skills
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="skillsCollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSkills">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Accounting">Accounting</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Administration">Administration</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Budgeting">Budgeting</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/neelam_cite/yr9wdj0t/4/) is a working fiddle.

Here is a screenshot of the design for the above functionality that I am trying to create:

[image]

Comment: Fiddles are helpful, but please always include the relevant code within the question. This is for two reasons. Firstly, links can rot, so if the fiddle becomes unavailable your question cannot be answered. Secondly, people shouldn't have to go off-site in order to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan I was trying to follow the best practises and left out the code thinking it would be better to link out but I understand why it's best to include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to re-build the list of selected items each time one changes. As you can see from your current logic, trying to find the element which was unchecked becomes a pain to maintain.

To build the list you can use `:checked` to retrieve only the selected checkboxes, then `map()` to build an array of their values as an array of HTML strings, before appending that where required. Try this:

```js
$('input:checkbox[name="skills"]').change(function() {
  var values = $('input:checkbox[name="skills"]:checked').map(function() {
    //return `<span>${this.value.trim()}</span>`;
    return '<span>' + this.value.trim() + '</span>';
  }).get();

  $('#filter-2-result').empty().append(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Skills:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="filter" id="filter-2-result"><span class="deselect"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSkills">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#skillsCollapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="skillsCollapse">
          Skills
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="skillsCollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSkills">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Accounting">Accounting</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Administration">Administration</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="Budgeting">Budgeting</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks  @RoryMcCrossan, I am using gulp to minify the JS and its throwing an error because of the return statement, what should that be changed to?

Comment: It may be that gulp doesn't like the string interpolation on that line. I've edited the question to use basic concatenation instead

Comment: That works @RoryMcCrossan thank you, I have accepted your answer, however the last little bit I'm not sure about is adding the x button next to the selected item to clear it. Like in my screenshot.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. To do that you would just need to add the HTML for the button in to the `<span>` you create, along with a delegated event handler to remove the items. If you get stuck with this I'd suggest starting a new question